# Remove Characters from XML Output in Postman

Tags: xmlhttprequest, postman

I'm making an XML API call in Postman and I get the following response:

```
<response>
   <result>
      <system>YYY:XXXXXXXXX</system>
   </result>
</response>
```

I created a variable from the content in "system", but I need to remove the "YYY:" from the front. Here is how I created the variable:

```
var response = xml2Json(responseBody);
var uuid = response["response"]["result"]["system"];
pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid);
```

If that could be formatted to remove any possible other characters before the colon - ex: "CCC:" or "ABC:" or "VAR1:" - that would be a bonus, but hard-coding this to remove exactly "YYY:" would solve the current problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, split String by character ":"

```
let text = "YYY:XXXXXXXXX";
console.log(text.split(":")[1]);
```

Apply to your code:

```
var response = xml2Json(responseBody);
var uuid = response["response"]["result"]["system"];
pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid.split(":")[1]);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I changed this - pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid); - to this pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid.split(":")[1]); - and it is no longer writing anything to that uuid variable in the collection. Do I need to add the "console.log" piece as well?

Comment: no, `console.log` just to log the value of variable to console.

Comment: OK, so then how should I change my code above? When I use - pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid); - it writes the full value to the variable. When I use - pm.collectionVariables.set("uuid", uuid.split(":")[1]); - it doesn't write anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: OK, that's what I did, but it wasn't working. Turns out, Postman was just messing up. I closed it and re-opened it, and all is well now. Thank you!